# the latest data to old data from top. i want scroll position last index of first of load. so from . i can scroll top to see new data. like whatsapp

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

when i scroll to top of last data iam doing api call , data appending , the latest data to old data from top. i want scroll position last index of first of load. so from . i can scroll top to see new data. like whatsapp`

```
const ifCloseToTop = ({ layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize }) => {
  return contentOffset.y == 0;
};
<ScrollView
  ref={ScrollViewRef}
  // onLayout will make sure it scroll to Bottom initially
  onLayout={() => ScrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd()}

  // We don't need `onContentSizeChanged`
  // this onScroll fetches data  when scroll reaches top
  // then it scrolls to last position as you asked

  onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (ifCloseToTop(nativeEvent)) {
      handleLoadMore()
      ScrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
        y: nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height,
        x: 0,
        animated: false,
      });
    }
  }}
  scrollEventThrottle={400}>
      <View style={styles.head}>
         // messages
      </View>
</ScrollView>
```

`